# clojure-koans: dosync inside do?

Tags: clojure

Was working my way through the [clojure koans](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans) when I came across an interesting one [in the `refs` section](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans/blob/master/src/koans/16_refs.clj#L15):

```
(= "better" (do
      (dosync (ref-set the-world "better"))
      @the-world))
```

I replaced this with:

```
(= "better" (dosync (ref-set the-world "better") @the-world))
```

to the same effect.

Is there any meaningful difference between the two? Why did the koan creator choose the first one?

Comment: Was dosync different in older versions of clojure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is, that you deref (read) that value within or outside of the transaction.  If the deref is part of the "transaction" (the `dosync`), then the value you get back it guaranteed to be the one you wrote as it's all part of one operation.

For this example the apparent effect is of course the same, since nothing works concurrently on your ref.  But if you have something else banging on it it looks like this:

```
user=> (def the-world (ref nil))
#'user/the-world
user=> (def disruptor (future (loop [] (dosync (ref-set the-world 0)) (recur))))
#'user/disruptor
user=> @the-world
0
user=> (dosync (ref-set the-world 1) @the-world)
1
user=> (dosync (ref-set the-world 1) @the-world)
1
user=> (do (dosync (ref-set the-world 1)) @the-world)
0
user=> (do (dosync (ref-set the-world 1)) @the-world)
0
```

The `disruptor` set the value to `0` in a background thread repeatedly.  So deref in/outside the transaction now matters.

Comment: Thanks, @cfrick! Going to rephrase in my own words so I can make sure I understand - basically, the koan version with the `dosync` inside the `do` guarantees the "freshest" value for the deref?